# Tuples failing at the spout, and seems they are not even reaching the Bolt

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have a topology running for a few days now and it started failing tuples from last couple of days. From the logs it seems that the tuples are not reaching the bolts, attached is the Storm UI screenshot.
I am ack'ing the tuples in *finally* in my code, so no case of un'acked tuples, and the timeout is set at 10sec, which is quite high than the time shown on the UI.

Any Hints ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECaxl.png)

Comment: I do see following message in the logs, not sure , if It's related..  worker.log:2018-02-16 03:59:16.727 o.a.s.k.PartitionManager [WARN] Removing the failed offsets for Partition{host=10.180.40.249:9992, topic=XXXXX_XXXX, partition=1} that are out of range: [9568, 9569, 9570, 9571, 9572, 9573, 9574, 9575, 9576, 9577, 9578, 9579, 9580, 9581, 9566]

Answer (score 1):

The log you're seeing is simply the Kafka spout telling you that it has fallen too far behind, and it has started skipping tuples.

I believe only acked tuples count for the complete latency metric https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/a4afacd9617d620f50cf026fc599821f7ac25c79/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/stats/SpoutExecutorStats.java#L54. Failed tuples don't (how would Storm know what the actual latency is for tuples that time out), so the complete latency you're seeing is only for the initial couple of acked tuples.

I think what's happening is that your tuples are reaching the bolt, and then either you're not acking them (or acking them more than once), or the tuples are taking too long to process so they time out while queued up for the bolt. Keep in mind that the tuple timeout starts when the spout emits the tuple, so time spent in the bolt's input queue counts. Since your initial couple of tuples are taking a while to process, I think the bolt queue gets backed up with tuples that are already timed out. The bolt doesn't discard tuples that are timed out, so the queued timed out tuples are preventing fresh tuples from being processed in time.

I'd raise the tuple timeout, and also cap the number of pending tuples by setting topology.max.spout.pending to whatever you think is reasonable (something like the number of tuples you think you can process within the timeout)

Comment: when you say started skipping tuples, does that mean.. it may be skipping tuples, that I expect it to process? regarding latency, I agree with the explanation , The tuples are definitely not reaching the bolt. (as I have a log statement there, which could have told me about that.)

Comment: Yes, sort of. While you can configure the KafkaSpout to only retry messages a certain number of times, that's not what's being logged here. The log you're seeing happens here https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/kafka/PartitionManager.java#L255. It will happen if the spout is retrying a message, and that message is no longer available in Kafka (e.g. due to topic compaction or segment deletion). I think for some reason the logged offsets aren't present in Kafka anymore. As a result the spout stops trying to fetch them.